# Is there a good bound for $\int_{a}^{\infty} x p(x) dx \approx \mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{P}(\{X > a\})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is there a good bound for $\int 1_{\{  x > a \}} x p(x) dx \approx \mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{P}(\{X > a\})$? That is, somd bound $d$ such that
$$
\left\lvert
\int 1_{\{  x > a \}} x p(x) dx - \mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{P}(\{X > a\})
\right\rvert <d
$$

Here $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a$ a constant. Here $1$ is the (logical) indicator function and $p$ is a pdf.

I want $d$ to be dependent on 
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] \text{ and } \text{Var}(X)
$$
so that either/both of $|\mathbb{E}[X] - a| \to \infty$ and $\text{Var}(X) \to 0$ brings about
$$
d(\mathbb{E}[X], \text{Var}(X)) \to 0.
$$
But a sufficient condition for the above convergence can be different.

As for $a$, it must be able to write $d=d(a)$ in an explicit formulation containing variable $a$; i.e., $d(a) = F(a)$ for some function $F$. But if such a formulation is not feasible at all, then we just leave it.

Comment: How is $\mathbb{E}[x]$ defined for for $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @GregordeCillia $\mathbb{E}[x] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x p(x) dx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) can be applied here. Firts we will have to rewite the term you want to estimate

$$
\int_{a}^\infty xp(x)dx - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{P}(X>a) = \int_{a}^\infty(x-\mathbb{E}(X))p(x)dx = \int_{a}^\infty(x-\mathbb{E}(X))d\mu(x) 
$$

Here I assumed that $X$ is a continuous variable. If you want to drop that assumption, you can use indicator functions instead of integral limits. $\mu$ is the probability measure produced by $X$.

$$
\left(\int_{a}^\infty(x-\mathbb{E}(X))d\mu(x)\right)^2\leq \int_{a}^\infty(x-\mathbb{E}(X))^2d\mu(x) \leq \mathbb{V}(X)
$$

Therefore, defining 
$$
d:= \left(\int_{a}^\infty xp(x)dx - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{P}(X>a)\right)
$$
with regarding $d = d(\mathbb{V}(X))$, we can see that
$$
d \underset{\mathbb{V}(X) \to 0}{\xrightarrow{\hspace{1cm}}} 0.
$$

Comment: To be equal to the variance, $a$ must be $-\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I just corrected that

Comment: The thing is the bound might be very poor in the case $a$ is high.

Comment: Yes indeed. An estimator that tends to zero as $a\rightarrow \infty$ would be much better.

Comment: Yes exactly. That's what I'm looking for by all means.

Comment: Oh. In this case take a look at [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)

Comment: I checked out the inequality but it gives only the lower bound whereas I need an upper bound. Is there anything like 'reverse' version of Chebyshev's that gives an upper bound?